# Javascript Convert JSONP data from string to Json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp

So i am not sure if i am doing this right.
I want to send markup over HTML (i am trying to create a widget) 
[Here](http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c9e94dd3000004a00ee98aa?callback=function) is the mocky response that i am expecting

so I create a simple jquery get like this

```
var jsonp_url = "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c9e901a3000004a00ee98a1?callback=myfunction";
    $.ajax({
                    url: jsonp_url,
                    type: 'GET',
                    jsonp: "callback",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (data) {
                     $('#example-widget-container').html(data.html)
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert('woops!'); //or whatever
                    }
                });
```

then created myFunction

```
function myfunction(data) {
        console.log(data);
}
```

The problem being that while, i get the response it comes as a string instead of a json or function. i am not sure how to extract the json from this (unless i do string manupulation). 
Any pointers would be helpful.

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kaeveey/n79ztyL2/7/)

> P.S.  Per https://www.mocky.io/ ,
>   **Jsonp Support - Add**
>   *?callback=myfunction* to your mocky URL to enable jsonp.

Comment: `type: 'GET',` is the default, you can remove it

Comment: `jsonp: "callback",` is the default, you can remove it

Comment: `contentType: "application/json",` is just wrong, you are making a GET request, the request has no body to describe the content-type of. Since you are using JSONP, this ignored anyway. JSONP doesn't allow you to set headers explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Delete `function myfunction`.
2. In the URL, replace `callback=myfunction` with `callback=?`.

jQuery will generate a function (your success function) and a function name for you.

Comment: i tried that. It still returns a string wrapped with a brackets. It is still a string though.

Comment: You can see that in the jsfiddle I had added.